# How can I highlight selected label in HIghcharts Timeline?

Tags: highcharts

I have data like this:
[Js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fuqevn41/)

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'x',
        type: 'timeline'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        visible: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        title: null,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Timeline of Space Exploration'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Info source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_space_exploration">www.wikipedia.org</a>'
    },
    tooltip: {
        style: {
            width: 300
        }
    },
    series: [{
        dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: false,
            format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
                '{point.x:%d %b %Y}</span><br/>{point.label}'
        },
        marker: {
            symbol: 'circle'
        },
        data: [{
            x: Date.UTC(1951, 5, 22),
            name: 'First dogs in space',
            label: '<div class="row">Granted chances = 38%<div class="col-sm-12">Interview = 24</div><div class="col-sm-12">Amendment = 24</div><div class="col-sm-12">Appeal = 24</div></div>',
          dataLabels: {
            allowOverlap: false,
            format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
                '</span><br/>{point.label}'
          },
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1957, 9, 4),
            name: 'First artificial satellite',
            label: 'First artificial satellite',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1959, 0, 4),
            name: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
            label: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1961, 3, 12),
            name: 'First human spaceflight',
            label: 'First human spaceflight',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1966, 1, 3),
            name: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
            label: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1969, 6, 20),
            name: 'First human on the Moon',
            label: 'First human on the Moon',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1971, 3, 19),
            name: 'First space station',
            label: 'First space station',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1971, 11, 2),
            name: 'First soft Mars landing',
            label: 'First soft Mars landing',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1976, 3, 17),
            name: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
            label: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1978, 11, 4),
            name: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
            label: 'First orbital exploration of Venus',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1986, 1, 19),
            name: 'First inhabited space station',
            label: 'First inhabited space station',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1989, 7, 8),
            name: 'First astrometric satellite',
            label: 'First astrometric satellite',
        }, {
            x: Date.UTC(1998, 10, 20),
            name: 'First multinational space station',
            label: 'First multinational space station',
        }]
    }]
});
```

Now I want to highlight the selected label Ex:
When I click on the first index which is 3 Feb 1996. The color of label gonna change and after the first index all gonna faded.

Like this:
[image]

And all other indexes after 3 Feb gonna fade or invisible Can you help me out from this?

I have tried below code in dataLabels as well as plotOption but it does not work for me.

```
allowPointSelect: true,
                        states: {
                            select: {
                                color: null,
                                borderWidth:5,
                                label:'Blue'
                            }
                        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `point.events.click` function to change a `dataLabel` color and remove points with a bigger index than the clicked one:

```
series: [{
    point: {
        events: {
            click: function() {
                var points = this.series.points;

                for (var i = points.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (i !== this.index) {
                        points[i].remove(false);
                    } else {
                        i = -1;
                    }
                }

                this.series.chart.redraw();

                this.dataLabel.attr({
                    fill: 'blue'
                });
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6ctuga0L/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.point.events.click

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#remove

Comment: Thanks, it's helped me a lot but I have one problem in this which is when I click on suppose x index the left indexes are gone. so after that how I can recover all indexes again if I want to click on another index?

Comment: Hi @vikash, You can use `setData` method on a series to apply the original data. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s96tu4Lq/

Comment: Thanks for the info one more problem I'm facing in this i.e when I select one index it's label color changed to blue but when I'm scrolling and clicking on reset zoom button the highlighted label will not anymore. Can you help me out from this?

Comment: Sure - please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/r1apd4uy/

Comment: Can I keep maintain highlighted label without the click on recover data?

Comment: @vikash - Do you mean something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7rLcs3w4/ ?

Comment: This is the same like before fiddle, Can you please check again?

Comment: No, that fiddle is different. Now you can mark multiple data labels and they are not removed.

Comment: Hi @ppotaczek, Can you tell me how I can redraw the whole chart keeping the selected item filled.

Comment: Hi @vikash, Could you create some live example? Also, I think it will be better if you create a new question with `highcharts` tag to separate the threads.